# How can we revisit screen command?

Tags: gnu-screen

Screen command is a command we use to ensure that the command is not interrupted. Well, internet connection is interrupted. So I want to go back.

I typed `screen` and go to a new screen.

What about if I want to visit the previous screen, where I ran the command?

Answer (score 5):

In case you have 1 screen session use:

```
screen -r
```

In case you have many you should first list them:

```
screen -ls

[root@gigan root]# screen -ls
There are screens on:
        31619.ttyp2.gigan       (Detached)
        4731.ttyp2.gigan        (Detached)
2 Sockets in /tmp/screens/S-root.
```

And then re-attach to the correct one:

```
[root@gigan root]#screen -r 31619.ttyp2.gigan
```

Those are other information can be found at http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

BTW. I recommend getting familiar with CTRL+A ^X x - this lock the screen of screen until you provide user password ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `screen -r`. From `man screen`:

```
   -r            Reattach to a detached screen process.
```

Answer (score 1):

or `screen -x`

> ‘-x’
>
> Attach to a session which is already attached elsewhere (multi-display mode). Screen refuses to attach from within itself. But when cascading multiple screens, loops are not detected; take care.

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -dr
```

`r` means “reattach” and `d` means “detach elsewhere” (in case your server hadn't noticed yet that the previous remote connection was interrupted).

If you have multiple `screen` instances running, you'll be shown a list. Call `screen -dr` with an extra argument that an unambiguous part of the name of the instance.

You can choose an instance name (session name) with `screen -S somename`.

Answer (score 0):

`screen -ls` or `screen -list` will generate you the list of screen sockets available currently.

`screen -x <socket_name>` attach an existing screen session

`screen -Dr <socket_name>` reattach and detach if necessary

`screen` or `screen -S <session_name>` will generate you a newer screen to work on.